# How do i move past a stuck PAM configuration on Ubuntu-pushed update?

Tags: updates

i am on Ubuntu 13.10 (probably have been upgrading since Ubuntu 10).  On a routine suggested update of a bunch of things including libkleo4, libkpgp4, libmessagecore4, girl.2-gudev1.0, kde-config-primactivity, konsolekalendar, etc. it sets up libsystemd-daemon0:amd64, systemd-services, and then starts on libpam-systemd:amd64 (204-0ubuntu19.1)— and that's where we get stuck.

The Debconf window opens for **PAM configuration** and says:

> No PAM profiles have been selected for use on this system. This would grant all users access without authenticating, and is not allowed. Please select at least one PAM profile from the available list.

The problem is, no matter what i check (or don't check) from the list below and press forward, it doesn't move forward.

The options to check are "Unix authentication", "Winbind NT/Active Directory authentication", "Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy", "GNOME Keyring Daemon - Login keyring management", "ConsoleKit Session Management", and "Inheritable Capabilities Management".

I don't know if i use or need PAM anything, but i would like to be able to complete recommended updates!

This is the second time an update has frozen here.  Advice?

Comment: Just appeared on my machine on software update of Ubuntu 19

Answer (score -1):

I used

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then  a terminal option screen (similar to the `pam-auth-update` screen) opens and you can (un-) select  with the <kbd>Space</kbd> key and move with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.